# How to check for updates when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

My application is quite simple: it downloads a JPG from a static URL with Picasso then displays it. However the picture behind the URL is regularly updated without changing the URL itself. When this happens, the application has to show a notification about it, even if the application haven't been started since boot.

My question is: what is the recommended and modern way to do it?

My biggest problem is that a lot of tutorials and documentation contain 3+ years old information and it's quite confusing which is the right for me without it being outdated.
Currently my concept is having a `BroadcastReceiver` which is subscribed to a boot event. This starts a `JobService` with an `Intent`, and the `onStartJob` method displays the notification. Am I right here or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for his comment, `WorkManager` is the way to go.

I've written my own `Worker` class and tried to enqueue a `Work` in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method:

```java
if (firstRun) {
            Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                    .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
                    .build();
            PeriodicWorkRequest updateRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NewPaperWorker.class, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .addTag("update")
                    .build();
            // Enqueue the work
            WorkManager
                    .getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .enqueue(updateRequest);

            // After starting the work, the firstRun variable can be set to false
            final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit()
                    .putBoolean("firstRun", false)
                    .apply();
}
```

The `Worker` shows a notification, that's its only job. It indeed sends a notification for the first time, but after that, despite of the `PeriodicWorkRequest`, it seems to stop completely. According to the developers' guide it should be showing notifications regularly about every 30 minutes. What am I missing?
I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 and enabled Autostart for the app.

Comment: Use `WorkManager`. You do not need an on-boot receiver; it will restart periodic work after a reboot.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WorkManager` is the solution for the original question, it's quite simple and straightforward to use, thnak you [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)!
After testing, I found the solution for my second question as well. The code above is absolutely fine, didn't need to modify it by a single character. The real problem was the Chinese phone, I had to turn off battery restrictions for my app to make the code work fine.
On a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 it was
`Battery & performance` -> `Battery entry/Settings icon` -> `App battery saver` -> search for app -> `No restrictions`
If it doesn't work for you, maybe
`Apps` -> `Permissions` -> `Autostart` -> `Turn on` will solve this issue.
Additional info about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906497/work-manager-on-chinese-roms-like-xiaomi-and-oppo-when-under-battery-optimizati/59907848#59907848) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465145/12410183).